# Need to speed up MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I had a query which is using to get various inputs to calculate Asset Ranking. To get the various values to calculate Asset Ranks based on user input, i am using multiple subqueries to a single table. But it is taking too much of time. Can anyone please help me to improvise this query?

```
 SELECT AssetId,
       AssetName,
       Isin,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH
   ORDER BY DDate ASC LIMIT 1) AS rafval,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH
   ORDER BY DDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS ralval,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH
   ORDER BY DDate ASC LIMIT 1) AS rbfval,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH
   ORDER BY DDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS rblval,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY
   ORDER BY DDate ASC LIMIT 1) AS rcfval,

  (SELECT DClose
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY
   ORDER BY DDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS rclval,

  (SELECT STD(DClose)
   FROM eod_data
   WHERE Isin=a.Isin
     AND DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY
   ORDER BY DDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS vstd
FROM assets a
INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId
INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId
WHERE asg.AssetGroupId=1
  AND a.IsActive=1;
```

In the above query, All the intervals which are mentioned in the subqueries are variables. They are coming from user input. Assets table containing 1000's of Assets And the eod_data will contain millions of records.

I created indexes also for all the Fields which are involving in where clause.

Table Structure
assets: AssetId,AssetName,Isin,IsActive | 
eod_data: Isin,DClose,DDate

The above query is taking almost 11 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Please find the Sample DB Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0a50/3

Comment: do have some sample date of both tables and the create of them ?

Comment: @Bernd Buffen thanks for the quick respose. Right now i dont have any sample data. i will creat some stuff. you need it to check data format or to test the query? SO that i will create sample tables

Comment: OK, you can put i on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: on http://sqlfiddle.com/ you can put the table and sample data

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Bernd Buffen Created Some stuff. Please check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75224c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my next try. i have test some different join. This is the fast way (1400 times faster). The STD() Column is not implemented in moment. Can you please check if the other output is correct

..and the final with STD() (i hope).

```
SELECT 
    a.AssetId
    , a.AssetName
    , a.Isin
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed2.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rafval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed3.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS ralval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed4.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rbfval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed5.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rblval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed6.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rcfval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed7.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rclval
    , COALESCE(ed.vstd,0) AS vstd
FROM (
    SELECT  
    ed.Isin
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rafval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_ralval
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL  3 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rbfval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL  3 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rblval
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 40 DAY  , EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rcfval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 40 DAY  , EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rclval
        , std(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 40 DAY  , NULL, DClose )) AS vstd
    FROM eod_data ed
    WHERE ed.DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH
    GROUP BY ed.Isin
    ORDER BY ed.EodDataId ASC
    ) ed
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed2 ON ed2.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed2.EodDataId = ed.id_rafval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed3 ON ed3.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed3.EodDataId = ed.id_ralval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed4 ON ed4.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed4.EodDataId = ed.id_rbfval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed5 ON ed5.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed5.EodDataId = ed.id_rblval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed6 ON ed6.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed6.EodDataId = ed.id_rcfval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed7 ON ed7.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed7.EodDataId = ed.id_rclval
INNER JOIN assets a ON a.Isin = ed.Isin
INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId
INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId
WHERE asg.AssetGroupId=1
  AND a.IsActive=1
ORDER BY a.AssetId;
SELECT 
    a.AssetId
    , a.AssetName
    , a.Isin
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed2.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rafval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed3.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS ralval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed4.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rbfval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed5.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rblval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed6.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rcfval
    , CAST(COALESCE(ed7.DClose,0) AS DECIMAL(20,4)) AS rclval
FROM (
    SELECT  
    ed.Isin
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rafval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_ralval
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL  3 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rbfval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL  3 MONTH, EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rblval
        , MIN(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 20 DAY  , EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rcfval
        , MAX(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 20 DAY  , EodDataId, NULL)) AS id_rclval
    FROM eod_data ed
    WHERE ed.DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH
    GROUP BY ed.Isin
    ORDER BY ed.DDate ASC
    ) ed
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed2 ON ed2.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed2.EodDataId = ed.id_rafval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed3 ON ed3.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed3.EodDataId = ed.id_ralval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed4 ON ed4.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed4.EodDataId = ed.id_rbfval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed5 ON ed5.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed5.EodDataId = ed.id_rblval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed6 ON ed6.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed6.EodDataId = ed.id_rcfval
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed7 ON ed7.Isin = ed.Isin AND ed7.EodDataId = ed.id_rclval
INNER JOIN assets a ON a.Isin = ed.Isin
INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId
INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId
WHERE asg.AssetGroupId=1
  AND a.IsActive=1
ORDER BY a.AssetId;
```

can you pls test it again ?

Comment: Hi @Bernd Buffen, Really Great Job. Superb Performance. But only thing is It is returning Minimum and Maximum DClose values in the given Interval. But i need First and Last Value In that interval. If we take an example of AssetId=1, In the 12 months result set, the first day DClose value is 42.6500. SO the rafval should be 42.6500. But in our query it is returning 38.6900. This is minimum value for this asset in 12 months period. Same as Last Day Value is 49.4400. But Our Query returning 49.7950 as ralval. which is maxmimum value in this interval. Please solve this. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: SELECT  STRAIGHT_JOIN AssetId, AssetName, a.Isin ,ed.DDate,ed.DClose  FROM eod_data ed LEFT JOIN assets a ON ed.Isin = a.Isin INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId WHERE ed.DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND asg.AssetGroupId=1  AND a.AssetId=1 ORDER BY DDate ASC; Just to check First and Last Value in our result.

Comment: Hi @Bernd Buffen any luck?

Comment: @Ravi - yes, but i must think a little bit on the best solution. i can work on it this evening. is it correct that all r[abc]lval values are the same. Its everytime the first row of the range and the last row, but the last is always the same ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Its the first and last values of that range. Actually there are 4 different kind of filters with date and interval. The date might be same or different.  For default view we will show now-default interval. But user can change the filters how ever he want and he can check the result. At that time we have to get all r[abc]lval. I hope you understand the situation.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bernd Buffen, wonderful, Really superb performance. Couldn't imagine. Yes the output is perfect. Double checked with my data. So only STD() is pending.  I don't know how to express my happiness.  Thank you.. Thank you soooo much for your time and effort.

Comment: @Ravi - OK, i can look this evening to implement the STD() and then i give you the final query

Comment: Ya please... Thank u

Comment: Hi @Bernd Buffen, Everything working good now. But Instead of this std(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 40 DAY  , NULL, DClose )) AS vstd, std(IF( DDate >= now()-INTERVAL 40 DAY  , DClose,  NULL)) AS vstd result matching with my result. Really great help. Once again thank you so much for your help. Thanks alot..:)

Comment: OK- sorry also 40 is wrong. i only change it for my tests. 20 is the correct value for the last 3 colums

Comment: Ya that is Ok. No problem.Anyway those integers coming from filters, not fixed. And the last date is early jan i think. thats why for 20day period, it is showing Null. Everything is good and performance is superb now...:)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this query. it use only one Join for all Columns, but with your sample data the last field are every time null, also with your query.

```
SELECT
      AssetId
    , AssetName
    , a.Isin
    , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH, DClose,null) )  AS rafval
    , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH, DClose,null) )  AS ralval
    , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH,  DClose,null) )  AS rbfval
    , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH,  DClose,null) )  AS rblval
    , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS rcfval
    , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS rclval
    , STD(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS vstd
FROM assets a
INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId
INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId
LEFT JOIN eod_data ed ON ed.Isin = a.Isin

WHERE asg.AssetGroupId=1
  AND a.IsActive=1
  GROUP BY AssetId;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->       AssetId
    ->     , AssetName
    ->     , a.Isin
    ->     , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH, DClose,null) )  AS rafval
    ->     , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 12 MONTH, DClose,null) )  AS ralval
    ->     , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH,  DClose,null) )  AS rbfval
    ->     , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 3 MONTH,  DClose,null) )  AS rblval
    ->     , min(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS rcfval
    ->     , max(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS rclval
    ->     , STD(IF(DDate >= now()-interval 20 DAY,   DClose,null) )  AS vstd
    -> FROM assets a
    -> INNER JOIN assetclasses ac ON ac.AssetClassId=a.AssetClassId
    -> INNER JOIN assetsubgroups asg ON asg.AssetSubGroupId=ac.AssetSubGroupId
    -> LEFT JOIN eod_data ed ON ed.Isin = a.Isin
    ->
    -> WHERE asg.AssetGroupId=1
    ->   AND a.IsActive=1
    ->   GROUP BY AssetId;
+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+
| AssetId | AssetName           | Isin    | rafval   | ralval   | rbfval   | rblval   | rcfval | rclval | vstd |
+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+
|       1 | AT ANDRITZ          | ANDR_AT | 97.5700  | 97.5700  | 97.5700  | 97.5700  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|       5 | AT BWT              | BWTV_AT | 98.2000  | 98.2000  | 98.2000  | 98.2000  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|       6 | AT ERSTE GROUP BANK | ERST_AT | 99.8000  | 99.8000  | 99.8000  | 99.8000  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|       7 | AT EVN              | EVNV_AT | 99.2600  | 99.2600  | 99.2600  | 99.2600  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|       8 | AT FLUGHAFEN WIEN   | VIEV_AT | 102.5200 | 102.5200 | 102.5200 | 102.5200 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      10 | AT IMMOFINANZ       | IMFI_AT | 104.1600 | 104.1600 | 104.1600 | 104.1600 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      11 | AT LENZING          | LENV_AT | 103.1300 | 103.1300 | 103.1300 | 103.1300 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      12 | AT MAYR MELNHOF     | MMKV_AT | 104.3700 | 104.3700 | 104.3700 | 104.3700 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      13 | AT MEINL EUR LAND   | MELV_AT | 103.0300 | 103.0300 | 103.0300 | 103.0300 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      14 | AT OMV              | OMVV_AT | 102.7200 | 102.7200 | 102.7200 | 102.7200 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      15 | AT PALFINGER        | PALF_AT | 101.2000 | 101.2000 | 101.2000 | 101.2000 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      17 | AT RHI AG           | RHIV_AT | 98.7800  | 98.7800  | 98.7800  | 98.7800  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      18 | AT SCHOELLER-BLECK  | SBOE_AT | 98.2100  | 98.2100  | 98.2100  | 98.2100  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      19 | AT SEMPERIT HDG     | SMPV_AT | 98.4500  | 98.4500  | 98.4500  | 98.4500  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
|      20 | AT TELEKOM AUSTRIA  | TELA_AT | 97.7400  | 97.7400  | 97.7400  | 97.7400  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL |
+---------+---------------------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+--------+--------+------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Once again thanks for your response.  Actually here for rafval I need first day value for that interval and for ralval, I need last day value for that interval... Like that remains subqueries also.  It's not min or Max values. And regarding sample data, yes it doesn't have enough data for all calculations. But please don't mind and gimme some idea like this to get first and last values in place of min and Max values in your query. Thank you

Comment: sorry - min and max must be correct . if you say **min** you get the lowest date and in the min is a **IF** statement that will pass through one the dates of the range. is this not correct ?

Comment: I am sorry to say that, It is not returning first and last value in that date interval. It is returning min and max values only. And one morething, i checked performance in my DB with real data. Total 1550 Assets matched to that query and it is taking 584.754s. I added some more data to fulfill all conditions. Please check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0a50/1

Comment: Hi @Ravi , is it possible to send me much more data. the execution times are always lower 1 mS and i cant really see if some Index works better. You can put it on some storage or send me directly to my email in profile. Then i will post the result here

Comment: Created the DB which more data, exactly replication of my present DB. Please download the file from here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y94w8xra88bgduu/aaa1test.zip?dl=0. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: @Ravi - thy, i will test it today

Comment: @Ravi - i have change one of my answers. please test it